# How to use a JBoss AS7 JNDI Datasource, from a Spring hibernate project running outside server (web application)?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss, jndi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do Migrate Java, Spring Project to use JNDI datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977554/how-do-migrate-java-spring-project-to-use-jndi-datasources)

How to use a JBoss AS7 JNDI Datasource, from a Spring hibernate project running outside server?

I am trying to find a way to access my JBoss AS7 JNDI Data Sources out side a web application. Can someone please tell me if this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.engfers.com/2008/08/07/exposing_accessing-jboss-jndi-objects_datasources-from-an-external-jvm/

Looks like what you're after.